# How to change the endDrawer icon in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

By default, the endDrawer icon in flutter is the hamburger icon. I wanna change it to a filter icon.

```
new Scaffold(
  endDrawer: Drawer(),
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        endDrawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.filter),
                    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                    tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: new Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(App());
```

Note the 'Builder' is necessary so that the IconButton gets the context underneath the Scaffold. Without that, it would instead be using the context of the App and therefore wouldn't be able to find the Scaffold.

A different (cleaner?) option would be to make a StatelessWidget that encloses IconButton.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rmtmckenzie. Really appreiciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried it but end up with two icons, maybe something has changed since this was originally answered?

Comment: @HillelCoren I'm only seeing one icon (although the particular icon looks like a stack of two), check it out on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/b84dedfc1f7c2636c2366d1b05f80aae?null_safety=true)

Comment: Thanks for this! There must be something else going on...